# At a time how many unacked messages can be in a Pub Sub push subscription

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

At a time how many unacked messages can be in a Pub Sub push subscription.

How it will affect the new delivery of messages if the subscription have more than 100 messages.

Comment: What do you mean by "in a Pub Sub push subscription?" Outstanding to the push endpoint? Stored for delivery to the push endpoint?

Comment: I mean unacked message count

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no limit to the number of unacked messages in a subscription. The limiting factor is the message retention duration on the subscription, which can be configured between 10 minutes and 7 days. Once a message age is beyond this value, the message is deleted even if it hasn't been acknowledged by a subscriber.

Messages could be unacked in one of two states: delivered to the subscriber or not yet delivered to the subscriber. Messages would not yet be delivered to the subscriber if the subscriber's ability to process messages cannot keep up with the rate at which messages are published. If your push endpoint has been responding with errors or deadlines have been expiring, then Cloud Pub/Sub backs off on delivery of more messages.

If you have lots of messages that are unacked, but already outstanding to the push endpoint, then this could delay the delivery of newly published messages based on the number of simultaneous outstanding messages currently allowed, the "push window."

The [quotas, limits and delivery rate section of the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/push#quotas_limits_and_delivery_rate) has more details.

Comment: I have this cloud function push endpoint which will nack the messages by returning the error when required based on the use case. Also have the backoff time 10(min backoff) to 15s(max backoff) and max delivery attempts as 5. Retention period set as 1 hour.

Dead letter configured after 5 attempts. 

Noticed when the unacked messages count exceeding around 100 messages, the new messages are not delivered to the push endpoint(cloud function). 

Expecting around 1000 messages per minute. At worst case , half of the messages can be nacked for retry.

Comment: couple of questions

1. If the Pub sub delaying deliveries due to the errors from the push endpoint, then the backoff retry declared in the subscription would not be honoured. is that correct?
2. Is there any guidelines, when we should use the retry mechanism considering number of outstanding messages which are outstanding to the push point/push window?
3. Changing the retention time, at these kind of scenarios , many outstanding messages to the push point, pub sub delays new messages . Is it a good idea.

Comment: Subscription retry settings and push backoff are different: the former only affects the message not acked while the latter affects _all_ deliveries. For push, a single nack slows down the delivery of all messages. I'm not sure what you mean by the second question. There is no choice of whether or not backoff happens with a push endpoint on nacks, it always happens and can't be configured. Changing the retention time is useful when you need to change how long you think it will take your subscriber to catch up and process messages in the event it is down.

Comment: **There is no choice of whether or not backoff happens with a push endpoint on nacks, it always happens and can't be configured**
   If a single nack due to the push point error happens, then at the retry setting's backoff time, the pub sub won't retry to deliver it. It really depends on the Push Window .

Comment: **Changing the retention time is useful when you need to change how long you think it will take your subscriber to catch up and process messages in the event it is down**
   We can not configure the retention properly when there are so many nacked messages in the subscription(due to the error) and delaying the new messages delivery due to the nack. 

Might lose the data if the push window increasing exponentially with respect to amount of nacked messages. we might lose the data if we configure the retention time less.

Comment: can you confirm the last 2 comments if it is right